# Importing styles from node_modules/@blueprintjs is showing error "Error: Failed to find '~@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint'"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, blueprint, webpacker

I tried to load styles from blueprintjs library and follow [this](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/css.md) instructions.

In file app/javascript/packs/application.js i have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import '../src/index.css';
import { App } from '../src/App';
import store from '../src/stores/store';
...
```

And in file app/javascript/src/index.css i have this:

```
@import '~@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint';
@import '~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons';
```

But when I run `rails webpacker:compile` I get the following error message:

> ERROR in ./app/javascript/src/index.css Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
>   ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Failed to find
>   '~@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint'   in [
>       /Users/EgorNikitin/todayilearned/app/javascript/src   ]

Any help would be helpful to me!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make sure that you installed blueprintjs

> yarn add @blueprintjs/core
>
> yarn add react react-dom react-transition-group

and also check that @blueprintjs folder is in the node modules folder. It should be great if there's @blueprintjs folder already